# php - comparing and extracting common array elements

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to compare values of inner arrays from a multidimensional array and extract those common values into another array.
I have tried using `array_intersect` along with a `foreach` loop but this is not giving me result, here the number of inner arrays is dynamic and generated from a different function. Have anyone tried before comparing array elements of a multidimensional array?

**My Array:**

```
    $days_filter = array(
    [0] => array(
        '00:00',
        '01:30',
        '02:30',
    ),
    [1] => array(
        '00:00',
        '01:30',
        '03:30',
    ),
    [2] => array(
        '00:30',
        '01:30',
        '02:30',
    ),
    [3] => array(
        '00:30',
        '01:30',
        '04:30',
    ),
);

$res_arr = $days_filter[0];
foreach ($days_filter as $filter) {
    $res_arr = array_intersect($res_arr, $filter);
}
```

**Expected output array:**

```
$res_arr = array(
    [0]=>'01:30'
)
```

because `01:30` is the common element of all inner arrays.

Comment: Please provide the expected output

Comment: Not a clear question, make it clear with some example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_intersect()` works for you..

```
$days_filter = array(
    0 => array(
        '00:00',
        '01:30',
        '02:30',
    ),
    1 => array(
        '00:00',
        '01:30',
        '03:30',
    ),
    2 => array(
        '00:30',
        '01:30',
        '02:30',
    ),
    3 => array(
        '00:30',
        '01:30',
        '04:30',
    ),
);
$first = $days_filter[0];

for($i=1; $i<count($days_filter); $i++)
{
  $result = array_intersect($first, $days_filter[$i]);
  $first = $result;
}

print_r($result);
```

This will give you :

```
Array
(
    [1] => 01:30
)
```

Comment: This is not the best answser to be honest... mine is. And yes I'm disappointed that such bad code gets approval.

Comment: why did you think that this is bad code ?? @JesusTheHun this code is working perfect try it ...

Comment: Semantically meaningless, barely readable and understandable, definitely confusing. A lot of code, some of it absolutely useless, i.e. two vars `$first` and `$result`, for something that can be done in one line of code.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PHP 5.6+ :

```
$res_arr = array_intersect(...$days_filter);
```

Otherwise :

```
$res_arr = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $days_filter);
```

And you are done :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
<?php

 $days_filter = array(
    0 => array(
        '00:00',
        '01:30',
        '02:30',
    ),
    1 => array(
        '00:00',
        '01:30',
        '03:30',
    ),
    2 => array(
        '00:30',
        '01:30',
        '02:30',
    ),
    3 => array(
        '00:30',
        '01:30',
        '04:30',
    ),
);


$result = array();

for($j = 0; $j < count($days_filter[0]); $j++)
{
    $tempArray = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($days_filter); $i++)
        $tempArray[] = $days_filter[$i][$j];

    if(count(array_unique($tempArray)) == 1)
        $result[] = $tempArray[0];
}

print_r($result);
```

**Working demo: [CLICK!!!](https://eval.in/574303)**

It's PHP version independent, so you don't need to think in how PHP5 version this script works.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this source from [source](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_intersect.asp)

```
<?php
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow");
$a2=array("e"=>"red","f"=>"green","g"=>"blue");

$result=array_intersect($a1,$a2);
print_r($result);
?>
```